# deploy.cmd not found on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I want to edit custom deployment to automate to execute MS Unit test cases. For that I tried to download the current(default) script file for editing but I could not see `deploy.cmd` under the path `Site\deployments\tools` folder.

And also I tried to download from tools=>download deployments scripts but got the following message

```
"{"Message":"Operation only supported if not using a custom deployment script"}"
```

Can you anyone help on this?

Comment: Can you explain bit more on the issue and also share the code?

Comment: I finally found a problem. The deploy.cmd is attached to source control and Azure takes from there. Thanks

Comment: @Ragu You could add it as answer that will help more communities who have the same issue.